# How to get the length of the maximum chain of a hash table?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I have a hash table program shown below

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <algorithm>
std::string fileName;
std::fstream readFile;
const int arraySize = 100;
int storeFile[arraySize]; 

class Hash 
{ 
    std::list<int> *table; 
    std::list<int>::iterator anItetator;
public:  
    int count = 0;
    int mod = 100; 
    Hash();
    Hash(int Value);  

    void insertItem(int key); 

    int hashFunction(int key) { 
        return (key % mod); 
    } 
  
    void loopHash(); 

    void displayHash(); 
};

Hash::Hash(){

} 

Hash::Hash(int b) 
{ 
    this->mod = b; 
    table = new std::list<int>[mod]; 
} 
  
void Hash::insertItem(int key) 
{ 
    int index = hashFunction(key); 
    table[index].push_back(key);  
} 

void Hash::displayHash() { 
  for (int i = 0; i < mod; i++) { 
    std::cout << i; 
    for (auto x : table[i]) 
      std::cout << " --> " << x; 
    std::cout << std::endl; 
  } 
}

void Hash::loopHash() {

for(anItetator = table->begin(); anItetator != table->end(); ++anItetator){

   if(table->empty()==true) {
    count++;
    }

   std::cout << "Total number of empty entries is: " << count;
   std::cout << "The largest chain is: "  << *std::max_element(table->begin(),table->end());
}

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int n = arraySize;

     Hash h(h.mod); 

     std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file: " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> argv[0];                                            

     fileName = argv[0];

     std::cout << "Attempting to read file " << fileName << std::endl;

     readFile.open(fileName); 

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 
     while (readFile >> storeFile[i])
     {
        h.insertItem(storeFile[i]); 
     }
}
     //h.displayHash();     
     h.loopHash();
     readFile.close();
     return 0;
}
```

However theres specific information i need from the results that im not quite sure how to find. These are 2 outputs

1. The number of empty elements in the hash table
2. The length of the longest chain

Ive attempted to do something like this with my `void Hash::loopHash()` however this function prints no values.

If anyone knows about hash-tables and can help me with this that would be great.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please don't use online competition sites as a way to learn good code-style and good habits, because they teach the opposite. I also suggest you get [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) or take a few classes to learn C++ properly, because your `loopHash` function contains a couple of pretty serious logical problems. Not to mention your really bad use of `argv[0]` as a temporary storage. Where or who taught you that?

Comment: I guess you need to use `anItetator` somehow in the `if` condition in `loopHash`?! It's spelled ite**r**ator, by the way.

Comment: It’s been popular lately to use `argv[0]` for storing things. Don’t do it — that’s not what it’s for. Just write `std::cin >> fileName;`

Comment: @molbdnilo: I assume that's a symptom of copy&paste programming. One person does something strange/wrong and suddenly you're seeing it more and more.

Answer (score 0):

`for(anItetator = table->begin(); anItetator != table->end(); ++anItetator){` iterates over the elements in the first `std::list`, because `table` is a pointer to a `list<>` (but that `list` is expected to the first of `mod` such lists effectively forming an array of `list`s).

What you should do to inspect each bucket in the hash table is access `table` as an array, using the array length you know you called `new` with to allocate the memory; e.g.

```
int num_empty_buckets = 0;
int longest_chain = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < mod; ++index) {
    if (table[index].empty())
        ++num_empty_buckets;
    longest_chain = std::max(table[index].size(), longest_chain);
}
// print 'em...
```